# Accessing extended file attributes without the 'user' prefix: impossibile?

Tags: java, java-17, file-attributes

It seems that Java (Java 17 and 20) is not able to read extended file attributes not having the prefix `user` in their name. I've done my research and test, but I'd like to have a confirmation before proceeding with a B-plan for my application.

More in detail: what I need is to read and write my own extended attributes to files. This is done by means of the `UserDefinedFileAttributeView` view, e.g.:

```
final var view = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
log.info("file: {} attributes {}", file, view.list());
```

My attributes are named `it.tidalwave.datamanager.id`, etc.; they have been handled so far by a Python application I wrote a few years ago (I'm porting it to Java before further development).

What it turns out is that Java internally retrieves the attributes, but filters away those whose names are not prefixed by `user` (this is obliquely mentioned in the code examples in the javadocs). A debugging screenshot of the involved JDK code proves this:

[image: debugging screenshot]

Furthermore, in the method that transforms the attribute name to the byte array expected by the native code, `user.` is explicitly prefixed.

I'm not aware of other ways to query extended attributes of files; other kinds of file attribute views are (such as `PosixFileAttributeView`) restricted to standard filesystem stuff. I've also tested it on Java 20, it's unchanged, and I'm not aware of new APIs in this context.

I'd like to have a confirmation.

Comment: If my source (https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Extended_attributes, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html) are trustworthy extended attributes should always be prefixed with a namespace and the namespace for user-attributes is "user.". That would mean that Java is correct in filtering out other namespaces.

Comment: If you use set via Java it prefixes your chosen name with "user.". Also its not the same on Windows which doesn't add or check for prefix.

Comment: We're discussing a different topic, that is whether Java is correct in enforcing the pattern. The Linux document says that there many namespaces, not only 'user': we could say that the UserDefinedFileAttributeView restriction is correct, but at this point the API is lacking the capability of managing other namespaces. Anyway, what I needed was a confirmation and it seems I got it.